# Python - filter by unique values in one list and specific string in a second list

Tags: python, list, list-comprehension

I have two lists

```
ids = [1,2,2,2,5]
names = ['yes', 'no','yes','yes','no']
```

I want to set(id) and filter name by 'no' maintaining there positions

So i end up with

```
[1,2,5]
['yes','no','no']
```

I just need to get a count of how many 'No's there are based of distinct ID's

Some kind of list comprehension maybe? zip?

Comment: That's actually a data example not an index. The array example is called id's, not indexes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this:

```
from collections import defaultdict
id = [1,2,2,2,5]
name = ['yes', 'no','yes','yes','no']
d = defaultdict(list)
for a, b in zip(id, name):
   d[a].append(b)

final_data = {a:b[0] for a, b in d.items()}
print(final_data.values().count("no"))
```

Output:

```
2
```